# Microsoft Graph findMeetingTimes endpoint not working

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

Please do not report as duplicate because all other topics have not solved my issue, thanks.

I'm using Microsoft Graph api to list and create calendar events, however I can't seem to make the findMeetingTimes endpoint work.

This is my authorization URL:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/consumers/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=xxxxx&response_type=code&redirect_uri=xxxxx&response_mode=form_post&scope=openid%20profile%20User.ReadWrite%20User.ReadBasic.All%20Sites.ReadWrite.All%20Contacts.ReadWrite%20People.Read%20Notes.ReadWrite.All%20Tasks.ReadWrite%20Mail.ReadWrite%20Files.ReadWrite.All%20Calendars.ReadWrite&state=12345
```

Then I request an access token using the same scopes:

```
$request = json_decode($guzzle->post('https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token', [
            'headers' => [
                'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            ],
            'form_params' => [
                'client_id' => 'xxxxx',
                'scope' => 'openid profile User.ReadWrite User.ReadBasic.All Sites.ReadWrite.All Contacts.ReadWrite People.Read Notes.ReadWrite.All Tasks.ReadWrite Mail.ReadWrite Files.ReadWrite.All Calendars.ReadWrite',
                'code' => $auth_code,
                'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
                'redirect_uri' => 'xxxxx',
                'client_secret' => 'xxxxx'
            ],
        ])->getBody()->getContents());
```

After that I'm trying the findMeetingTimes endpoint using:

```
$request = json_decode($guzzle->post('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/findMeetingTimes', [
            'headers' => [
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $accessToken,
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            ],
            'body' => '{
              "attendees": [
                {
                  "type": "required",
                  "emailAddress": {
                    "name": "My Name",
                    "address": "myemail@hotmail.com"
                  }
                }
              ],
              "timeConstraint": {
                "activityDomain":"work",
                "timeslots": [
                  {
                    "start": {
                      "dateTime": "2019-04-02T09:00:00",
                      "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
                    },
                    "end": {
                      "dateTime": "2019-04-03T17:00:00",
                      "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }',
        ])->getBody()->getContents());
```

However, it keeps returning:

```
401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.

You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.
```

Who's going to be my hero? :/

Comment: No one able to help me out with this?

Comment: Are you using a work or school account when authenticating through your authorization URL?

Comment: No, just a regular Microsoft account @CameronDowner

Answer (score 4):

This is by design. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/findmeetingtimes-example):

> **Note** The `findMeetingTimes` action is currently available to Office 365 work or school mailboxes, but not personal, outlook.com mailboxes.