# Microsoft Graph API keeps returning 401 Unauthorized

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Please do not report as duplicate because all other topics have not solved my issue, thanks.

I'm using Microsoft Graph API to list and create calendar events, however, I can't seem to make the `findMeetingTimes` endpoint work.

This is my authorization URL:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/consumers/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
  ?client_id=xxxxx
  &response_type=code
  &redirect_uri=xxxxx
  &response_mode=form_post
  &scope=openid profile User.ReadWrite User.ReadBasic.All Sites.ReadWrite.All Contacts.ReadWrite People.Read Notes.ReadWrite.All Tasks.ReadWrite Mail.ReadWrite Files.ReadWrite.All Calendars.ReadWrite
  &state=12345
```

Then I request an access token using the same scopes:

```
$request = json_decode($guzzle->post('https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token', [
    'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'],
    'form_params' => [
        'client_id' => 'xxxxx',
        'scope' => 'openid profile User.ReadWrite User.ReadBasic.All Sites.ReadWrite.All Contacts.ReadWrite People.Read Notes.ReadWrite.All Tasks.ReadWrite Mail.ReadWrite Files.ReadWrite.All Calendars.ReadWrite',
        'code' => $auth_code,
        'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
        'redirect_uri' => 'xxxxx',
        'client_secret' => 'xxxxx'
    ],
])->getBody()->getContents());
```

After that I'm trying the findMeetingTimes endpoint using:

```
$request = json_decode($guzzle->post('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/findMeetingTimes', [
    'headers' => [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $accessToken,
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    ],
    'body' => '{
        "attendees": [
        {
            "type": "required",
            "emailAddress": {
            "name": "My Name",
            "address": "myemail@hotmail.com"
            }
        }
        ],
        "timeConstraint": {
        "activityDomain":"work",
        "timeslots": [
            {
            "start": {
                "dateTime": "2019-04-02T09:00:00",
                "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
            },
            "end": {
                "dateTime": "2019-04-03T17:00:00",
                "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
            }
            }
        ]
        }
    }',
    ])->getBody()->getContents());
```

However, it keeps returning:

> 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
>
> You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.

Does anyone know what I'm missing? Note that I'm not using a Microsoft work/school account, just my regular one. (Does it matter?)

Comment: is your redirect url in `http://` or `https://`

Comment: graph only redirect to https;//

Comment: I'm using Ngrok, with Https. @iamawesome

Comment: Duplicate of your own question [Microsoft Graph findMeetingTimes endpoint not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55445935/microsoft-graph-findmeetingtimes-endpoint-not-working)

Answer (score 2):

Its not possible to call this endpoint with personal accounts, this is metioned very cleary in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-findmeetingtimes?view=graph-rest-1.0)

[image]